# Aggregation fails despite using $out with a "BufBuilder attempted to grow()" Error

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB to aggregate some data. The query can also be seen in the error message. Although I'm using `$out` to export the results to another collection, the aggregation fails. Any suggestions ?

```
   OperationFailure: command SON([('aggregate', u'h'), ('pipeline',
 [{'$unwind': '$hashtags'}, {'$group': {u'replied': {'$push': u'$replied'},
 u'retweeted': {'$push': u'$retweeted'}, u'followers': {'$push':
 u'$followers'}, u'user': {'$push': u'$user'}, u'date': {'$push': 
u'$date'}, '_id': '$hashtags', '_ids': {'$push': u'$_id'}}}, {'$out': 
'Hashtags'}]), ('allowDiskUse', True)]) failed: exception: BufBuilder 
attempted to grow() to 134217728 bytes, past the 64MB limit.
```

Comment: Not a "get out of jail free card". You cannot try and push all the matching documents to a "hashtag" into a single document object. That 64MB restriction per document still applies. You are doing the wrong thing by trying to do this. Also would have been "nicer" of you to post your "code" rather than just the error. Nicely formatted so we can read it.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn You are right. I'm changing my initial schema design now. Although it would make visualization stuff easier but this really doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NeilLunn You can add it as an answer and I'll Best-Answer it.

Comment: Try upgrading your mongodb and driver. This seems to be a closed bug from mongodb 2.4.x. Ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9538

Comment: I'm using MongoDB 2.6

Comment: My answer here may (or may not) help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37193362/993683