# Mongo aggregation and MongoError: exception: BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 134217728 bytes, past the 64MB limit

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to aggregate data from my Mongo collection to produce some statistics for FreeCodeCamp by making a large json file of the data to use later.

I'm running into the error in the title. There doesn't seem to be a lot of information about this, and the other posts here on SO don't have an answer. I'm using the latest version of MongoDB and drivers.

I suspect there is probably a better way to run this aggregation, but it runs fine on a subset of my collection. My full collection is ~7GB.

I'm running the script via `node aggScript.js > ~/Desktop/output.json`
Here is the relevant code:

```
MongoClient.connect(secrets.db, function(err, database) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  database.collection('user').aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        'completedChallenges': {
          $exists: true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        'completedChallenges': {
          $ne: ''
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        'completedChallenges': {
          $ne: null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        '_id': 1, 'completedChallenges': {
          $addToSet: '$completedChallenges'
        }
      }
    }
  ], {
    allowDiskUse: true
  }, function(err, results) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    var aggData = results.map(function(camper) {
      return _.flatten(camper.completedChallenges.map(function(challenges) {
        return challenges.map(function(challenge) {
          return {
            name: challenge.name,
            completedDate: challenge.completedDate,
            solution: challenge.solution
          };
        });
      }), true);
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(aggData));
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregate returns a single document containing all the result data, which limits how much data can be returned to the maximum BSON document size.

Assuming that you do actually want all this data, there are two options:

- Use `aggregateCursor` instead of `aggregate`. This returns a cursor rather than a single document, which you can then iterate over
- add a [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) stage as the last stage of your pipeline. This tells mongodb to write your aggregation data to the specified collection. The aggregate command itself returns no data and you then query that collection as you would any other.

Comment: the aggregateCursor function has been removed
The old .aggregate() method now has split personality:

    Old varargs of pipeline ops
    An array of pipeline ops as first argument, second argument "options" ```(such as {allowDiskUsage: true}

    )```

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the result object you are building became too large. This kind of issue should not be impacted by the version. [The fix implemented for 2.5.0 only prevents the crash from occurring](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9538).

You need to filter ($match) properly to have the data which you need in result. Also group with proper fields. The results are put into buffer of 64MB. So reduce your data. [$project](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) only the columns you require in result. Not whole documents.

You can combine your 3 $match objects to single to reduce pipelines.

```
{
  $match: {
    'completedChallenges': {
       $exists: true,
       $ne: null,
       $ne: ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "The fix implemented for 2.5.0 only prevents the crash from occurring." Parts of your answer look like copy/paste from here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9538, you should reference it if you're paraphrasing

Comment: @JoeRocc: Forgot to add link. Added now. You can also edit answer and add link. Thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I couldn't debug the problem so I ended up abandoning the aggregation approach. Instead I just iterated through each entry and created a new collection. Here's a stripped down shell script which might help you see what I mean:

```
db.new_collection.ensureIndex({my_key:1}); //for performance, not a necessity
db.old_collection.find({}).noCursorTimeout().forEach(function(doc) {

    db.new_collection.update(
       { my_key: doc.my_key },
       { 
           $push: { stuff: doc.stuff, other_stuff: doc.other_stuff},
            $inc: { thing: doc.thing},
       },
       { upsert: true }
    );

});
```

I don't imagine that this approach would suit everyone, but hopefully that helps anyone who was in my particular situation.