# Mongodb, get distinct values of a field and output the values as single document

Tags: mongodb, distinct-values

I have a large collection of documents which have the following structure

```
{'_id':ObjectId(something),...., 'id':1}
{'_id':ObjectId(something),....,'id':2}
....
```

I want to get the distinct ids (i.e., values in the 'id' field). The following code can solve my problem to some extent,

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$id'},{ "$out": "exist_indexes" }],{allowDiskUse: true});
```

However, in the output collection, exist_indexes, the distinct values are stored as **multiple documents**. Something like

```
{'_id': 1}
{'_id': 2}
....
```

How can I output the distinct values as `a single document` in the output collection? Something like this

```
{"_id": [1,2,3,....]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$addToSet` in `$group`,

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      ids: { $addToSet: "$id" } // change field name ids to as you want
    }
  },
  { $project: { _id: "$ids" } }, // you can skip this if you don't want to change field name
  { $out: "exist_indexes" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3SssTB-hQzj)

Comment: Thank you! I never knew I could set "null" to _id. My collection is fairly large. I encountered this problem "BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 67108871 bytes, past the 64MB limit.". Do you know how to deal with this limit? Thanks!

Comment: Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467454/mongo-aggregation-and-mongoerror-exception-bufbuilder-attempted-to-grow-to-1) and answers. you can spread it in multiple documents instead one.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tired the answers in the link you provided. Using "$out" did not help. By "spread it in multiple documents instead one", do you mean I can control the number of documents to be generated in "exist_indexes" (e.g., storing the resulst in 2 or 3 documents)? How exactly can I do that?

Comment: yes, what is the purpose of storing only ids in a single document, what kind of use?

Comment: I actually need the distinct values in "id" to be put in a list/vector in a python script. I have ~20m documents. So I cannot use python to fetch this collection directly, as the collection is over 400G. Then, I think I should do an immediate step in MongoDB to create a document (or several) to store these ids which I thought should be faster for python to fetch. The orignal method I used (stated in my question) will generate ~20m separate documents in "exist_indexes". Iterating over this ~20m documents in python is doable, but takes several days. Fewer documents in exist_indexes, the better.

Comment: Its huge data, you can do pagination or use some filters to retrieve data like date wise or some other filters, otherwise its not accurate process to select whole data together..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  Perhaps I will use some filters to break the task into smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

The agenda is to get distinct value, then why bothering about _id in output. Use MongoDB inbuild distinct function.

> db.mycollection.distinct("id")

Make sure index should be created first of field id before executing the query

Comment: It is a fairly large collection. The cap is reached: "distinct too big, 16mb cap"

Comment: Please create an index of id field, and then try.